# Share photo with caption on Facebook

Tags: facebook, photos, share-menu

I'd like to share a **photo with caption** pre-filled from my app, for example on facebook. How do I do it?

I know how to share photo or how to share text, but how do I share them together?

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Android 2.1 and the latest official Facebook App.

I go to the gallery and long-press on an image. In the menu, select SHARE and in the list of apps displayed choose FACEBOOK.

I immediately am taken to a text field where I can type in a caption.

by default the images are sent to the MOBILE UPLOADS folder/album, but you can create a new album and specify that as your desired upload location.